# Строковой дерева считывается не правильно

Tags: c++, c, дерево

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто знает. Я уже несколько дней сижу с этой ошибкой и не могу понять что не так.
По заданию нужно считать n-арное дерево из файла, но почему-то после считывания значения деревьев меняются на не понятные символы хотя во время выполнения функции значения все верные у всех поддеревьев.
вот мой код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "locale.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct tnode 
{
    char* key;
    int id = 0;
    int status = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int lvl = 0;
    vector <struct tnode*> vect;
    struct tnode* parent;
};

struct tnode* addtree(tnode* tree, char* w, int tt, int tz, int id) 
{
    int d = 0;
    while (d < tt - 1) 
    {
        if(!tree->vect.empty()) 
            if(tree->vect.back()) 
                tree = tree->vect.back();
        d++;
    }
    if (tt == 0) 
    {
        tree->key = w;
        tree->id = id;
        tree->lvl = tt + 1;
        return tree;
    }
    else 
    {
        tnode* trer = new tnode;
        trer->id = id;
        trer->parent = tree;
        trer->key = w;
        trer->lvl = tt + 1;
        tree->vect.push_back(trer);
        tree->status = 1;
        tree->count++;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < tt - 1) 
        {
            if (tree->parent) tree = tree->parent;
            i++;
        }
        return tree;
    }
    return tree;
}
int tt = 0;
int id = 0;

void deserialize(tnode*& root, FILE* fp)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char val[250];
    char nik[259];
    if (!fgets(val,200,fp)) 
    {
        printf("%s ", root->key);
        return ;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while (i < 100) 
    {
        if (val[i] == '.') 
            b++;
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    int d;
    if (b > 0) 
    {
        while (i < strlen(val)) 
        {
            if (val[b + i] != 0 && val[b + i] != ' ') 
            {
                val[i] = val[b + i];
            }
            else 
            {
                d = i;
                val[i] = 0;
    
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    id++;
    root = addtree(root, val, b, tt, id);
    deserialize(root, fp);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    tnode* tree = new tnode;
    FILE* file = fopen("tree.txt", "r");
    deserialize(tree, file);
    puts(tree->key);
    return 0;
}
```

вот текст файла tree.txt:

```
Ann
.Boris
..CAT
..Dora
...Eva
...Fred
..Gova
...Helmut
....Marta
.....Bred
.....Stiv
.....Jon
......Tom
...Nata
.Nina
```

Comment: Просто интересно: зачем вам понадобилось встановливать русскую локаль? Причем дважды...

Comment: Еще почему у вас дерево и нода смешались? Это вообще-то разные сущности

Comment: И что за бред у вас в десериализации? Как это по-вашему должно работать?

Comment: Укажите в коде, на каком моменте считанные значения верны, а на каком уже нет. В виде комментариев.

Comment: И переименуйте вопрос. Вряд-ли кто-то в курсе, кто такой этот Ваш "строковой дерева".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полностью переписал `deserialize()` функцию используя C++ стиль.

Структуру самого узла дерева `tnode` не менял, чтобы она осталась совместима с вашей программой, только добавил внутрь структуры деструктор `~tnode()` - это функция для автоматической очистки ресурсов узла и всё его поддерево, всегда нужно очищать все ресурсы программы.

Также добавил `dump()` функцию, она выводит дерево в красивом виде в консоль.

Весь код ниже, включая примеры использования всех функций (с вашим входным файлом `tree.txt`):

[Попробовать код онлайн!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1222133#main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "locale.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define LN { std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl; }

struct tnode 
{
    char* key = 0;
    int id = 0;
    int status = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int lvl = 0;
    vector <struct tnode*> vect;
    struct tnode* parent = 0;
    ~tnode() {
        if (key) delete[] key;
        for (auto & e: vect)
            if (e) delete e;
    }
};

struct tnode* addtree(tnode* tree, char* w, int tt, int tz, int id) 
{
    int d = 0;
    while (d < tt - 1) 
    {
        if(!tree->vect.empty()) 
            if(tree->vect.back()) 
                tree = tree->vect.back();
        d++;
    }
    if (tt == 0) 
    {
        tree->key = w;
        tree->id = id;
        tree->lvl = tt + 1;
        return tree;
    }
    else 
    {
        tnode* trer = new tnode;
        trer->id = id;
        trer->parent = tree;
        trer->key = w;
        trer->lvl = tt + 1;
        tree->vect.push_back(trer);
        tree->status = 1;
        tree->count++;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < tt - 1) 
        {
            if (tree->parent) tree = tree->parent;
            i++;
        }
        return tree;
    }
    return tree;
}
int tt = 0;
int id = 0;

tnode * deserialize(std::string const & file_name)
{
    std::ifstream inf(file_name);
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inf, line)) {
        line.erase(0, line.find_first_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ")); // left trim
        line.erase(line.find_last_not_of("\t\n\v\f\r ") + 1); // right trim
        if (line.empty())
            continue;
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    std::function<std::tuple<size_t, std::unique_ptr<tnode>>(size_t, size_t)> drec;
    drec = [&lines, &drec](size_t il, size_t offset){
        if (il >= lines.size() || (offset > 0 && lines[il][offset - 1] != '.'))
            return std::make_tuple(il, std::unique_ptr<tnode>());
        if (offset > lines[il].length() || (offset > 0 && lines[il][offset - 1] != '.') || (offset < lines[il].length() && lines[il][offset] == '.'))
            throw std::runtime_error("Wrong offset of node '" + lines[il] + "'! Should be " + std::to_string(offset));
        auto node = std::make_unique<tnode>();
        auto skey = lines[il].substr(offset);
        node->key = new char[skey.length() + 1];
        node->key[skey.length()] = 0;
        std::copy(skey.begin(), skey.end(), node->key);
        ++il;
        while (true) {
            auto sres = drec(il, offset + 1);
            il = std::get<0>(sres);
            auto & child = std::get<1>(sres);
            if (!child) break;
            child->parent = node.get();
            node->vect.push_back(child.release());
        }
        return std::make_tuple(il, std::move(node));
    };
    return std::get<1>(drec(0, 0)).release();
}

void dump(tnode const & node, std::string const & prefix = "", bool root = true, bool last = true) {
    std::cout << prefix << (root ? "" : (last ? "\\-" : "|-")) << (node.key ? node.key : "") << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < node.vect.size(); ++i)
        dump(*node.vect[i], prefix + (root ? "" : (last ? "  " : "| ")), false, i + 1 >= node.vect.size());
}

int main()
{
    try {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        auto proot = deserialize("tree.txt");
        dump(*proot);
        delete proot;
        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception const & ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Ann
|-Boris
| |-CAT
| |-Dora
| | |-Eva
| | \-Fred
| \-Gova
|   |-Helmut
|   | \-Marta
|   |   |-Bred
|   |   |-Stiv
|   |   \-Jon
|   |     \-Tom
|   \-Nata
\-Nina
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ВикторШалагин Пожалуйста! :)